# General printing raster and/or vector images

Tags: c++, python, c

I'm looking for some API for printing.

Basically what I want to achieve is to print set of pixels(monochromatic bitmap which I store in memory) onto the generic paper format (A4,A5..etc.).

What I think that would be minimum API is:

- printer devices list
- printer buffer where I could send my in-memory pixmap (ex. like winXP printer tasks folder)
- some API which would translate SI dimensions onto printer resolution, or according to previous - in memory pixmap (ex. 450x250) onto paper in appropriate resolution.

What I was considering is postScript, but I've some old LPT drived laserjet which probably doesn't support *PS.

Currently I'm trying to find something interesting in Qt - QGraphicsView.

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/qgraphicsview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you got close, look at [Printing in Qt](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/printing.html). There is the [QPrinter](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qprinter.html) class that implements some of what you are looking for. It is implmenetent as a `QPaintDevice`. This means that any widget that can render itself on the screen can be printed. This also mean you don't need to render to a bitmap to print, you can use Qt widgets or drawing functions for printing

On a side note, check the version number of the Qt documentation, the last release of Qt is 4.5, 4.6 is in beta.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to [investigate wx python for printing](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Printing).  Learning the framework might be a bit of an overhead for you though!  I've had success with that in the past, both on windows and linux.

I've also used [reportlab](http://www.reportlab.org/downloads.html) to make PDFs which are pretty easy to print using the minimum of OS interaction.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to create a BMP file, and then just use the standard OS services to print that file.  PIL will accept data in either raster or vector form.